# return an element from array of json output

Tags: json

I am trying to extract specific values returned from google api

```
<?php 
$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=19.1629924,72.83930190&destinations=19.1802370,72.8554149&sensor=false';

$contents = file_get_contents($url); 
$contents = utf8_encode($contents); 
$array=json_decode($contents); 
echo  $array['rows']['elements']['distance']['value'];

?>
```

I expected the value of 4238 to be returned. Instead I get an error:

```
`PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in test9.php on` line 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Te correct solution is:

```
echo  $array->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value;
```

Do the following to see the json:

```
<?php

$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=19.1629924,72.83930190&destinations=19.1802370,72.8554149&sensor=false';

$contents = file_get_contents($url); 
$contents = utf8_encode($contents); 
echo "<pre>";
echo $contents;
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
$array=json_decode($contents); 
echo  $array->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value;

?>
```

http://www.json.org/

have you tried node.js?

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved the problem:

```
$array=json_decode($contents, true);
echo  $array['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
```